How to getting Cookies from Express.js to Next.js 14
I'm working on a Next.js 14 application with an Express.js backend. I'm trying to set a JWT token as a cookie after the user logs in, but the cookie is not showing up in the browser's cookies storage.
Here's what I did:
1. Backend (Express.js):
I created a /login route where the user logs in. After login, I generate a JWT token and try to store it as a cookie using res.cookie().
Here is my Express.js login route:
export const login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // User authentication
    const user = await AuthService.login(email, password);

    // Generate JWT token
    const token = generateToken({ id: user._id, email: user.email });

    // Set token as cookie
    setTokenCookie(res, token);

    res.status(200).json({
      status: 200,
      success: true,
      message: 'Login successful',
      user: user,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'Login failed' });
  }
};

const setTokenCookie = (res, token) => {
  const cookieOptions = {
    httpOnly: true, // Cookie not accessible from JavaScript
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', // Use secure cookie in production
    sameSite: 'lax', // Prevent CSRF attacks
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 hour
  };

  res.cookie('authToken', token, cookieOptions);
};

const generateToken = (payload) => {
  return jwt.sign(payload, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1h' });
};

2. Frontend (Next.js 14):
I call the /login API from the frontend using fetch. I have set credentials: 'include' to allow the cookie to be saved.
Here’s how I’m making the request:
const loginUser = async (email, password) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/auth/login`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    credentials: 'include',  // Allow cookies to be included
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
  });

  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};

3. Problem:

Even though the login request is successful and the backend sends the Set-Cookie header, I can't see the authToken in the browser's cookies under Application → Cookies.

I also checked the Network tab, but the Set-Cookie header is missing.


4. My Setup:
Express.js backend running on localhost:5000  | Next.js frontend running on localhost:3000
I’m using cors with the following configuration
app.use(cors({
  origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL, // Next.js frontend URL
  credentials: true,              // Allow cookies
}));

Why isn’t the cookie (authToken) being saved in the browser ?
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!
I checked that secure: false is used in development.
I made sure credentials: 'include' is added in the frontend fetch request.
I verified the res.cookie() is being called on the backend and that the token is generated correctly.
I checked that CORS is configured to allow cookies.

Based on this answer - could you try:
Cookies.set('authToken', response.headers['authToken'])
using js-cookie inside your loginUser function
